# How to randomize a slice?

Tags: python

I am trying to make battleship and I am making the ships in one list "board" and the length of the ships will be determined by slices. I am trying to move the ships by random.choice but I soon realized random.choice only moves one element at a time but the ships have 2 - 5 elements. I am trying to see if I can randomize the slices in the list as the the unit assigned on the slice. random.shuffle does not seem to work.

```
import random

board = "o"

board = [board] * 49

ship_two_space = board[0:2]

ship_three_space = board[0:3]

ship_three_space_second = board[0:3]

ship_four_space = board[0:4]

ship_five_space = board[0:5]
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear and the code you provide not helpful at all since it doesn't show what you've tried or are trying to do.

Comment: Do the slices always start at 0? What are the board dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Ship positions cannot overlap - use a set to document occupied space

```
occupied = set()
```

Define the specifications

```
N = 49
board = ['o'] * N
ship_specs = [('two_space', 2), ('three_space1', 3), ('three_space2', 3),
              ('four_space', 4), ('five_space', 5)]
```

Start making ships - use collections.namedtuple to *define* a ship

```
Ship = collections.namedtuple('Ship', ('name','indices', 'slice'))

def get_position(length):
    '''Determine the unique position indices of a ship'''

    start = random.randint(0, N-length)
    indices = range(start, start + length)
    if not occupied.intersection(indices):
        occupied.update(indices)
        return indices, slice(start, start + length)
    else:
        return get_position(length)

ships = []

for name, length in ship_specs:
    indices, _slice = get_position(length)
    ships.append(Ship(name, indices, _slice))


print(board)
for ship in ships:
    board[ship.slice] = str(len(ship.indices))*len(ship.indices)
print(board)
print([(ship.name, ship.slice) for ship in ships])

>>> 
['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']
['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', '2', '2', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', 'o', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', '3', '3', '3', 'o', 'o', 'o']
[('two_space', slice(10, 12, None)), ('three_space1', slice(43, 46, None)), ('three_space2', slice(16, 19, None)), ('four_space', slice(12, 16, None)), ('five_space', slice(20, 25, None))]
>>>
```